# Angularjs: maintain http body after redirect

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, redirect

Hi everybody and sorry for the English (if you found some mistakes),

I have the next question: I am in the page A and I call a web service that returns a JSON in the body, after this I redirect to another page B. 
My question: after the redirection, body is kept ? In oder words, can I get or access to the body (if the body contains the JSON)?

Example

The web service:

```
app.service('LoginService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.retrieveUser = function(username, password) {
        var url = app.baseURI + username+"/"+password;
        return $http.get(url);
    };
```

...

JS redirect

```
self.login = function(username, password){
            LoginService.retrieveUser(username, password)
            .success(function (data) {
                if(data.usuario.rol == "G")
window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/Natureadventure/html/gerente/gestionarActividades.html";
            }).error(function(data){
                $scope.loginForm.password.$setValidity("password", false);
            });
        };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is completely client-sided, so, aside from setting something in localStorage, cookies or sessionStorage, no, you will not be able to do this.

The way around it is to turn your Angular application into a single-page application; you never really change the page of the website as such, but Angular can emulate the changing of your web page (i.e the content and the layout) through a library like [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) or [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

The downside to this is that if you are either stuck with ugly hashbang URLs or you enable html5Mode, which breaks if you refresh the page. The way to fix that is to either a) stick with hashbang URLs or b) make your server redirect any unknown request to your index.html and let angular do the routing for you.